# Send a message to a person, who added a comment on Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-webhooks

I wanna create a similar thing, that is described [here](https://bot.andter.com/autopm) for my business page on facebook. There are lots of alternatives like chatfuel and manychat, but I wanna have the same Auto PM, but more flexible. What I did so far, I connected to: webhooks and messenger APIs. I wrote these lines of code, which allow me to see all changes in the feed of my Business Page.

```
app.post("/api/webhooks", jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    const jsonBody = req.body || '';
    if (typeof jsonBody !== 'object' || !jsonBody.entry || jsonBody.object !== 'page') { return res.send('no body'); }
    // else
    const { message, sender_id } = jsonBody.entry[0].changes[0].value;
    console.log(message);
    if (!message) { return res.send('no message'); }
    bot.say(sender_id, 'hey there, Mr. P!');
    return res.send('post request');
});
```

As I said this piece of code allows me to see, who made changes on my business page, so I can take even user's id. So I thought, if I know user's ID I can send him a message, but I get the error below, when I'm trying to send a message.

```
{ message: '(#100) No matching user found',
  type: 'OAuthException',
  code: 100,
  error_subcode: 2018001,
  fbtrace_id: 'CkNJQpdP6A9' }
```

- bot - is a third party npm package, which called bootbot. https://github.com/Charca/bootbot

What I'm doing wrong? Do I need maybe more permissions for some actions?

Comment: You can not message a user, just because they commented on your page. (Your page can reply to their comment in private, though, so that only that particular user will be able to see your reply.)

Comment: thanks for your reply, but just tell me how they do this?
youtube.com/watch?v=JNGK_0SHXLo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,  I found how to resolve this thing and it's pretty easy to do. Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/object/private_replies

Comment: Is there a way to send a structured message this way ? From what I see, the message object is limited to plain text. I'd like to send a more structured message with call to actions like buttons with postback, and such. Is it possible to send this kind of message with private_replies ?